# Number formatting remove numbers after dot add comma at thousands

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently output `1844.6304`

desired output - comma thousands trim after dot ( no rounding )

```
1,844
```

I was looking some time on forums and can't find a solution to solve both cases.

Comment: Math.floor(1844.6304) it and then follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Its even simpler like this

```js
var n = 1844.6304,
s =  Math.floor(n).toLocaleString();
console.log(s); //"1,844"
alert(s);
```

Comment: That work if you're in the US, but as a Canadian, I see `1 844`

Comment: Didn't know that about [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: @cforcloud Yeah well, it take the local string format and it is set in the computer. You can pass an argument though, maybe you can check if you can force the format?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function intWithCommas(x) {
    return Math.floor(x).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Example:

```
> intWithCommas(1844.6304)
'1,844'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function toCommaInteger(number){
    var result = "" + ~~number;
    var length = result.length;
    var limit = result[0] === "-" ? 1 : 0;
    for(var i = length-3; i > limit; i-=3 ){
        result = result.substring(0,i) + "," + result.substring(i,length);
        length++;
    }
    return result;
}


toCommaInteger(123589.85315)  => 123,589
toCommaInteger(-1289.15315)   => -1,289
toCommaInteger(5)             => 5
```